# how to turn a string of numbers to binary in C++?

Tags: c++, string, binary, bitset

Hi I have a string that looks like this:

```
std::string myString = "123456789";
```

Is there a way for me to turn that string of a decimal number to a binary number?

Comment: `std::stoi` parses string to int. Is that what you want?

Comment: or `std::bitset` to get a bitset.

Comment: @Cplusplusbeginner show us the error

Comment: I tried using std::stoi but I got this error message:
{
 "resource": "th path of the file",
 "owner": "cpptools",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "could not convert 'std::__cxx11::stoi(myString, 0, 10)' from 'int' to 'std::__cxx11::string' {aka 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'}",
 "source": "gcc",
 "startLineNumber": 188,
 "startColumn": 21,
 "endLineNumber": 188,
 "endColumn": 21
}

Comment: @Cplusplusbeginner show us the code you used, please.

Comment: please include a [mcve] of your code and the error message in the question. Code/error messages in comments are not readable

Comment: I don't know if you want a string that holds the binary number or if you want to parse the value of the string into a data type like integer ... . Please provide more information.

Comment: The code looks similiar to this:

std::string funtion(std::string input) {
       std::string output = "";
       for (int i = 0; i <= input.size(); i++) {
              if (input[i] == 'a') {
                      output += '1';
              }
        }
        return output;
}

Comment: @Bananenkönig (cool name) I basically want to turn the string to an int and then that to binary.

Comment: So what do you mean with binary? All data is stored binary as your PC can't understand different things than 0 and 1 :D

Comment: @Bananenkönig yes I know that. But there a decimal numbers and binary numbers. I want to turn a decimal number into a binary number

Comment: @Cplusplusbeginner there is no "decimal number". It's all binary data.

Comment: from a mathematical standpoint: 15 is a decimal number. 1111 is the binary form of that. If your computer wants to store 15 as data it will store it as 1111

Comment: binary and decimal are just different representations of the same number. binary `1111` and decimal `15` are the same number. Very likely you need not convert anything.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 that is exactly what I said in my last comment

Comment: @Cplusplusbeginner what he's trying to say is that `int` has no base (binary, decimal, etc) since that makes no sense. You can't convert from a "Decimal int" to a "Binary int" because that makes no sense. `int i = 15;` and `int i = 0b111;` are identical in all ways.

Comment: I was refering to "there a decimal numbers and binary numbers. I want to turn a decimal number into a binary number" you don't "turn numbers into binary / decimal". Thats similar to having a 15 in english and now I want to turn that into a spanish 15 ;). The whole point of this discussion is just that your question isnt quite clear. The string is already a representation of the number `123456789`. And that number does not change, whehter you look at it in binary or decimal. Anyhow, I hope one of the answers can help

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili but you can convert from an int to something like a binary string

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Yes it is similiar to that. And I hope you realize that translating is an actual thing people do. The reason my question is not quite clear, is because I was not quite sure what the best way to do it was. What I was doing is turning the string to an int , and then trying to turn it to a string, whose content was supposed to be the binary form of that int.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse string to int, here is how you do it:

```
std::string strDec = "123456789";
int i = std::stoi(strDec);
```

If you then want to convert int to string but this time in binary representation, here is a way to do that:

```
std::string strBin = std::bitset<32>(i).to_string();
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mxx63zeKv)

---

Or, you can use [{fmt}](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) library:

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
  std::string strDec = "123456789";
  std::string strBin = fmt::format("{:032b}", std::stoi(strDec));
}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nbPqvK78a)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you want to convert the string representing a number into an actual integer.
As stated by some others: `std::stoi` "string to int". Depending on the size of the numbers, you may want to use `std::stoull`. this is the same thing but for `long long`, a 64 bit integer.

Next you want to convert that number back into string. the easiest thing to use that provides this functionality is `std::bitset` and its `to_string` member function. The constructor of bitset requires an unsigned long long, so we'll use `std::stoull`, the unsigned variant.

This can all be combined into a single line of code:

```
myString = std::bitset<64>{ std::stoull(myString) }.to_string();  // 64 bits to fit a long long
```

After this operation, You'll be left with a string that looks like this: `0000000000000000000000000000000000000111010110111100110100010101`
You may want to get rid of the zero's up front.
We can use the string's `find` and `erase`

```
myString.erase( 0, myString.find('1') );
```

This will erase all characters from position 0 until the first 1's position.